# How to send ecommerceBundle in React Native Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

There is [this doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce#product_clicks_selections)

```
// Define product with relevant parameters

Bundle product1 = new Bundle();
product1.putString( Param.ITEM_ID, "sku1234"); // ITEM_ID or ITEM_NAME is required
product1.putString( Param.ITEM_NAME, "Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt");
product1.putString( Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Apparel/Men/Shirts");
product1.putString( Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "Blue");
product1.putString( Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google");
product1.putDouble( Param.PRICE, 29.99 );
product1.putString( Param.CURRENCY, "USD" ); // Item-level currency unused today
product1.putLong( Param.INDEX, 1 ); // Position of the item in the list

// Prepare ecommerce bundle

Bundle ecommerceBundle = new Bundle();
ecommerceBundle.putBundle( "items", product1 );

// Set relevant action-level parameters

ecommerceBundle.putString( Param.ITEM_LIST, "Search Results" ); // Optional list name

// Log select_content event with ecommerce bundle

mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent( Event.SELECT_CONTENT, ecommerceBundle );
```

How to send data like this in React Native?